# The requested was not found on this server - Form validation (Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a contact form page using PHP,JQuery, HTML5 and Bootstrap css. 
PHP to send mails, JQuery to validate user input and Bootstrap css to highlight the input fields.
In my code i am able to validate the user input but when i click on submit button nothing happens.
In my HTML code when i replace form id from "id=contact-form" to form then i am able to send mails but validation not happen. Please tell me what i am doing wrong.

```
PHP Code-
 <?php

$name= $_POST['name'];
 $email= $_POST['email'];
  $Message= $_POST['Message'];

 $to=" s.nandan@niraame.com , shantanunandan8@gmail.com ";
  $from="";
   $subject="New query from customer ";
    $body = "Customer name : $name\n\n";
       $body .= "Customer Message : $Message\n\n";
        $body .= "Customer email id : $email\n\n";

 ini_set("SMTP","mail.niraame.com");
 mail($to,$subject,$from,$body);

?>

HTML Code- 

 <form method="post" action="contact-form-submission.php" class="form-horizontal" id="contact-form">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="email">Email Address</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email address">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="subject">Subject</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select id="subject" name="subject">
                <option value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
                <option value="service">Feedback</option>
                <option value="suggestions">Suggestion</option>
                <option value="support">Question</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="message">Message</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="8" class="span5" placeholder="The message you want to send to us."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit Message</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>

JQuery Code- 

$(window).load(function(){
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var message = $("#message").val();
var contact = $("#contact").val();

$.post("contact-form-submission.php", {
name1: name,
email1: email,
mess age1: message,
contact1: contact
}, function(data) {
$("#returnmessage").append(data); // Append returned message to message paragraph.
if (data == "Your Query has been received, We will contact you soon.") {
$("#contact-form")[0].reset(); // To reset form fields on success.
}
});

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#contact-form').validate({
rules: {
name: {
minlength: 2,
required: true
},
email: {
required: true,
email: true
},
message: {
minlength: 2,
required: true
}
},
highlight: function (element) {
$(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
},
success: function (element) {
element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
.closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
}
});
});
});
```

Comment: Your logic seems wrong, you are submitting your form on page load instead of the success function of your validator.

Comment: @ jeroen  Sir i am very new to JQuery and i tried this code but i am not able to find out where i am doing wrong

Comment: @jeroen In any case i want to recive the data from the user either its right or wrong thats why i wrote the submit code at the page load. The validation is only to inform the user that he is putting wrong data and if he wants he can correct it.

Answer (score 1):

As @jeroen mentioned, currently you are attempting to post the form on page load. Let's try an approach where you submit the form when a user clicks the submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // let's attach an event handler to the form's submission
  $('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from submitting normally, this allows us to interject your client side validation

    // perform your validation

    // if valid, post
    // else show errors, etc
  }
});
```

Also, keep in mind that it's best practice to perform validation both on the server AND the client. At the very least, ALWAYS on the server.